# ZapOfDingBats font is not visible properly on the output pdf

Tags: java, fonts, itext

I am using ZapfDingBats font in itext to show a text on the Pdf. I followed the general code to display text using ZapfDingBats font as below:-

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.lowagie.text.*;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class Chap0201 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Chapter 2 example 1: Chunks and fonts");

        // step 1: creation of a document-object
        Document document = new Document();

        try {

            // step 2:
            // we create a writer that listens to the document
            // and directs a PDF-stream to a file
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C://Chap0201.pdf"));

            // step 3: we open the document
            document.open();

            // step 4: we add content to the document
            Font fonts;
            fonts = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.ZAPFDINGBATS, 12, Font.NORMAL);
           // for (int i = 0; i < fonts.length - 1; i++) {
                Chunk chunk = new Chunk("This is some", fonts);
                document.add(new Phrase(chunk));
               // document.add(new Phrase(new Chunk(" font. ",
                //fonts[i]).setTextRise((i % 2 == 0) ? -6 : 6)));
          //  }
            document.add(new Phrase(new Chunk("This text is underlined",
            FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.UNDERLINE))));
            document.add(new Phrase(new Chunk("This font is of type ITALIC | STRIKETHRU",
            FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.ITALIC | Font.STRIKETHRU))));
            Chunk ck = new Chunk("This text has a yellow background color", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12));
            ck.setBackground(new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00));
            document.add(new Phrase(ck));
        }
        catch(DocumentException de) {
            System.err.println(de.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

        // step 5: we close the document
        document.close();
    }
}
```

I just followed the above text to show text in Pdf. But all the text printed using ZapOfDingBats font appears in the form of dark filled shapes(i.e squares,triangle etc.)
[image]

Please suggest as why this is happening. As I followed each and everything correctly.

Comment: ZapfDingbats is a symbol font. thus, what did you expect?

Comment: The font is called ZapfDingbats, not ZapOfDingBats.

Comment: Just added to this How can I use ZapOfDingBats font in java using Font object. I didn't find a way to show ZapOfDingBats text in Java Swing. I tried using Font object

Font dqFont = new Font(name,style,size);

I didn't find a name as "ZapOfDingBats" to display this Java Font. Is there anyway I can get this Font object for such kind of Font and can display it on a label.

Comment: @a_horse's comment might give a hint why ZapOfDingBats is hard to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZapfDingbats is a dingbat font.

*The term continues to be used in the computer industry to describe fonts that have symbols and shapes in the positions designated for alphabetical or numeric characters.*

(wikipedia, http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat)

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think it will show some alphabet. And it unessarily is seen in the form of bullets and triangles.